# Geometric distribution and the probability of getting success at "first try"?

Tags: probability-distributions

If one knows the probability of success $p$,

then how does one calculate the probability of getting success at "first try" using geometric distribution?

Is it simply the probability of success? Are the successive events independent?

Comment: Hard to guess about independence if you give us no information at all.

Comment: @lulu I was just suggesting that if the probability of getting success on first try would be $p$, then why wouldn't the success on any try be also $p$?

Comment: If the random variable has a geometric distribution, then it is the count of *trials until the first success* in an indefinite sequence of *independent* Bernoulli trials with an *identical* success rate.  [Sometimes the count of *failures before the first success*, depending on text.]

Comment: Independence depends on context, it's not axiomatic.  For sports, say, people sometimes assume "trending" (so that recent victories increase the odds of future victories) or, alternatively, mean reversion (so recent victories lower the probability of subsequent victories).  Or you can just have independence.

Comment: @lulu Well would e.g. winning in lottery be independent?

Comment: If the trials are not independent it is not a geometric distribution. @lulu

Comment: In the usual setting, yes.  The usual setting is:  a random number is uniformly chosen from a fixed list and the gambler selects from the list.

Comment: @GrahamKemp  Oh, agreed. But I think the OP is unsure of the setting (of course I might have the question wrong).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the random variable has a geometric distribution, then it is the count of trials until the first success in an indefinite sequence of independent Bernoulli trials with an identical success rate. [Sometimes the count of failures before the first success, depending on text.  We'll assume the former.]

If $X\sim \mathcal{Geo_1}(p)$ then $\mathsf P(X=k)=p(1-p)^{k-1}\quad\bigl[k\in\{1,..,\infty\}\bigr]$.

You appear to require $\mathsf P(X=1)$, the probability that there is one trial until the first success. (The count of trials until the first success is one.)

Comment: But does "one trial" change depending of whether one limits to some interval of trials or considers all possible trials?

Comment: What? @mavavilj

Comment: Let says one considers, whether one wins on the first week on some year in lottery. Then is "on the first week" equal to $X=1$?